# Use a NSPageController with Interfacebuilder to set a view

Tags: macos, cocoa, xcode6

I want to connect the PageController with the three ViewControllers below to set the content of the lower SplitView.
Any ideas on how to do it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is not standard way to embed them. 
Connect the ViewControllers via a custom segue and subclass it to behave like you need.